# Why doesn't Bootstrap's clearfix class work here?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a website that features photo galleries. Many of the images in the photo galleries are different sizes, but all of their widths are the same. In tablet and desktop versions, the photo galleries form 4 neat columns and the rows align correctly. In the smartphone version, they form 2 columns (the way I want) but the rows are misaligned. This is the issue.

How do I remedy this? I tried to use clearfix between the problematic images. An interesting thing happened: the hour after editing the files, clearfix worked great. But soon after that the issue returned. I have restarted my computer, browser, clear the cache...still this persists.

I have tested the misaligned photo galleries in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, on a Windows and Samsung Galaxy smartphone. Still there.

You can view the misaligned photo galleries live here...this artist paints nude models, so...adult content advisory: www.ericeickmann.com/panel.html

My CSS is the standard Bootstrap CSS folder, with a couple minor changes, ex. typography. I am also using Lightbox: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2 Note that clearfix stopped working before I added Lightbox's code.

This is my HTML:

```
    <!-- row 1 //-->
    <div class="row portfolio-thumbs leading">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- row 2 //-->
    <div class="row portfolio-thumbs leading">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <a href="" data-lightbox="panel" data-title=''>
                <img src=""/>
                    <p></p>
                </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to include your CSS as well.

Comment: you have an extra `<h2>` in your sample code here:    `<p>IN HIND SIGHT, 2014 <br>Acrylic on Panel 7" x 7.5"</h2></p></a>`

Comment: @Shaggy I am using the standard Bootstrap CSS with only minor changes, for example, the background color and typography. If I was to include ALL of my CSS it would take me an hour to indent everything.

Comment: @dippas Thank you for pointing that out! :) I fixed it, but the clearfix issue isn't resolved.

Comment: Here's a starter demo. Please modify it to show your problem and add a link to your question. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/5z57uoem/

Comment: @isherwood You can't just go to the website link and see the problem live? I don't know how to replicate the issue because I don't know exactly what is going wrong, and I have a lot of JS and CSS to paste into those little boxes. I'm not trying to be difficult, I just don't understand your comment. Please explain.

Comment: It's difficult to do any sort of troubleshooting or testing on someone else's site. You're likely to get a very quick answer if you're able to demonstrate a simplified version of the issue you're facing. Best of luck.

Comment: The issue is the `visible-sm` class that's set on the `clearfix` div between the 2nd and 3rd items of each set. When the viewport is smaller than the 768px breakpoint, the style on that goes from `display: block!important` to `display: none!important`, basically removing it from the layout, which doesn't seem to be what you want to have happening.

Comment: @ultranaut That is correct, I do not want the image to be hidden. In a previous question related to this, it was suggested that clearfix will "reset" the new row which is having issues because the individual image heights are different. I suppose this is a Bootstart bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further reading, I think the solution to this bug is "masonry" style CSS, Javascript and JQuery. Clearfix is only one solution to creating Bootstrap photo galleries with dissimilar heights, but I think a more elegant solution lies with the above-mentioned techniques.